# how to load lazy component with angular without ngModule?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

In angular is it possible to load component in lazy without specify `ngModule`?

Today I use:

```
 { path: '..', loadChildren: () => import('./my.module').then(m => m.myModule) }
```

Can I do something like this code:

```
 { path: '..', component: () => import('./my.component') }
```

Is it possible? if so how?

Comment: Just put the component in it’s own module

Answer (score 0):

I found [this tutorial](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/lazy-load-components-in-angular-596357ab05d8) which I think can help you. In order, you need to declare the component as part of this module, then to load component only when it's used, helped by **ComponentFactoryResolver** and **Injector**

Comment: This solution boils down to, make a single component module and import your component differently than with the router, then jump through a few extra hoops to render it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can load component lazily without including it in NgModule. you can import component in code where you need and then by using ComponentFactory Resolver and ViewComponentRef , check the [article](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/loading-components-dynamically-in-angular-cd13b9fdb715)